# Brick texture with multiple colors

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

Using the Brick texture is it possible to have more than 2 solid colored bricks unmixed with the bias?

I have been putting a color ramp on the output of the texture node, at constant to get 2 colors.  Is there a way to further split these into 3+ colors, to provide even more random colors?

I tried to apply Robin Betts solution, however if I do it that way, the noise texture effects the color smoothness, I added a color ramp, which seemed to help and put the noise texture onto a brick, but now the color smoothness is a grey outline around all the bricks. I would like it to be a black.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7DR7.jpg)

node layout with color ramp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4CDA.jpg)

node layout with color ramp results

[image]

results of node layout as per Robin Betts solution Below.

[image]

node layout Copied from Robin Betts Solution below

Comment: Please attach images to better explain your question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Bricks node puts out a random-per-brick *blend* of the two input brick colors, biased at Bias  = -1 to Color 1, and Bias = 1 to Color 2. So you can  quantize the blend, and map it to colors, as much as you like:

[image]

[image]

I've added a tree which uses the range of colors to switch between completely different textures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If i wanted to texture each colour separately how would i individualize them after the ramp?

Comment: @NickSieben .. see edit.. but you're more likely to want to use the brick colors to control the location/scale of the lookup into a _single_  image or procedural texture? In which case it would be simpler: you would add/multiply  the output color  with  the Vector  input of your  single texture.. you could mix the color over the texture downstream.. or.. or.. all sorts of options. Maybe you need to be more specific, in another  question.

Comment: this helps alot thanks

Comment: see my updated question, I'm getting different results than you

Answer (score 1):

Nick Sieben, try adjusting the first "greater than" value from zero to 0.2 as shown in Robin Betts answer. That will help with adjusting the color of the mortar.