# How can I make a Voronoi fracture in Blender?

Tags: mesh, texturing, faces, cell-fracture

How can I make something like in the picture in Blender?

I would also like to apply different textures on each cell.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Voronoi texture node can be set to output 'Position', (The position of the feature-point of the cell, in the space the texture is given,) and 'Color', (a random color per cell). These numbers let you make switches, in a similar way to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/145945/35559).

First, the [Kintsugi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kintsugi) cracks, as described by @Chris:

[image]

- The 'Scale' input gives a general size of the fragments
- The 'Thickness' input gives the thickness of the cracks
- The fiddling about with division-by-thickness, etc. gives a 0-1 range of distacnce *inside* the crack-mask, so it can be put through a color-ramp to give the profile of the gold-bump.
- The straight Black/White mask is sent off to be the factor between the gold, and background material.

The *Texture Coordinate* and Scale are branched off to keep a second, parallel *Voronoi* node in sync. with the above, distance-to-edge one...

[image]

The second *Voronoi* node generates the same pattern, but with different information. (*Distance* from feature-point, *Position* of feature-point, and random *Color* per cell.)

Here, we've tapped out the Red channel of the random color, which gives us a random number between 0 and 1 per cell. The 'Multiply Add' makes a crude sort of seed, to change the random options; keep the *Multiply* much larger than the number of choices. The result is a randomish number between 0 and 10 per cell.

The number can be used as a switch by cascading *Mix*es, between shaders, or colors, or anything else...

[image]

Above are a couple of entries. If the random number is less than 3, the output is the result of the mix so far. Otherwise, the new color. Then the mix is handed on down the chain. In this example, the switch is between image textures. The overall result is a random-image-per-cell.

The whole tree looks like this:

[image]

This is the sort of result:

[image]

A simplified version, mixing 5 colors..

[image]

Comment: This is Amazing! Thank you very much for posting this! Is there any way to add a different displacements on each cell also?

Comment: See...I told ya...he is the procedural master of all classes!!!

Comment: Hi, @NivSad! Thank you!. I'm going to edit to include a .blend to share. So, while I'm at it, do you want a random _amount_ of displacement, or random _pattern_ of displacement?

Comment: @Chris I'm no master.. here are just some examples out of many... check out [Erindale](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGMyyn2FdEFcDfP1wQRh5l) and [Simon Thommes](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzCcofKd2wi8UvdutOkxp2w) out there.. and on this site, [Rich Sedman](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/29586/rich-sedman). Also important not to get carried away, and remember what you want, in the end, is a _picture_. Not a bunch of nodes :D. So, [Ian Hubert](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbmxZRQk-X0p-TOxd6PEYJA).

Comment: Hi @Robin Betts, core idea was to have like a leather on one cell, one to be rock, one plastic... So I am just curious to know, is there any way to make different displacements for each cell individually?
Thank you for taking time to solve it, I really appreciate!

Comment: @Niv You can mix _anything_ using your random-number-per-cell, so, you could use _Mix Shader_ nodes in place of _Mix RGB_ nodes, in exactly the same way, to mix entirely different shaders, instead of images. However, this will make for a large and unwieldy shader-tree. Unless you have to automate this, because, say, you have to make dozens of balls, I'm not sure your own  geometric Fracture method wouldn't be more manageable?

Comment: @Robin Betts I think I understand you now. 
Anyway, It would be really nice if blender would make just a checkbox while doing a cell fracture to keep the margin. It would be much shorter way then yours and mine. Hope it will come some day :D
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

check this out:

[image]

of course you could also use bump to have a bit more "3d" look like in your pic

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sending it but I would like then to apply different textures on each cell (eg: one to be metal, one to be letter...) i am not sure if this can be done over nodes. I guess I should use something like cell fracture but then I don’t have this border around... Do you maybe have some other way?

Comment: damn...i should read better :( ...but Robin Betts can help...and do this with shader nodes, i am sure :D

Comment: No worries, I done a cell fracture and then separate outlines and added a solidify modifier to outlines. It’s similar effect and a bit longer method so If someone find a better solution to this, I would really appreciate :)