# Alternatives for compare nodes in blender 2.79

Tags: materials, node-editor, shader-nodes

So I was trying to follow a tutorial on a voronoi fracture in blender and I found [this tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220711/how-can-i-make-a-voronoi-fracture-in-blender?fbclid=IwAR13IhnRn7erM-IbxL95vf7fPKbtqV7o2orOCR-4vo7t2YHz6gOB3nJABwE), which was really good but for the application I'm looking to use it in, I have to use blender v2.79 as I am trying to create a material for Stud.io, a lego design program.

Blender 2.79 doesn't have compare nodes and to the best of my admittedly amateur knowledge, multiplication and division nodes. Does anyone know of any alternatives to these nodes? I have included the current state of my material, I can live without the division, multiplication and bump but the compare node (crack mask) is essential.

[image: Current state of my material]

Comment: HI. In 2.79 the Voronoi Texture node is not available in the Shader Node Editor. If you copy and paste the object you have this node tree for into 2.79, you will see when you open a Shader Node Editor that there isn't any output from what gets put in place by 2.79 for a Voronoi Texture node. The Voronoi texture node in 2.79 is only available in a Texture node tree.